# Is a 10 year old uncashed paycheck still good?

Tags: banking, paycheck

I found a paycheck from a previous job that is 10 years old and I never cashed it. The business is still operating, is it still good?

Comment: Country? In the US, no; contact them to trade it for a new check.

Answer (score 8):

You probably can't deposit the check directly, but there are mechanisms in place to get your money through other means. In the US, all states and territories have an unclaimed property registry. Before you contact the company that wrote the check, you should check that registry in your state. You will have to provide proof that you are the intended recipient, having the original check in your possession should make that considerably easier.